# Array in SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem making a SQL Query with an array in my WHERE clause.

For example:

My Array:

```
$myarray[1] = "hi";
$myarray[2] = "there";
$myarray[3] = "everybody";
```

My MySQL Statement:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE title='".$myarray[]."'
```

Is there any way to realize that?
I solved it myself like this:

```
for(...) {
$where = $where." title='".$myarray[$count]."' OR ";
}
$where = substr($where , 0, -3);
.....
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ".$where."
```

But if i had thousands of entries in my array, the SQL Statement would be too big and slow, right?

Thanks

Comment: 'OR' is the SQL equivalent of the devil and will slow down even a small request.

Comment: don't forget to `foreach($myarray as $key => $val) $myarray[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use mysql's [IN-function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

EDIT: As amosrevira said, you need to escape you strings in the array.

```
$myarray[1] = "'hi'";
$myarray[2] = "'there'";
$myarray[3] = "'everybody'";

$newarray = implode(", ", $myarray); //makes format 'hi', 'there', 'everybody' 

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE title IN ($newarray);
```

Comment: i think he needs to add quotes to the strings on the array though..

Comment: @njaknjak thats obviously wrong answer. you don't have to add quotes manually - it's job for PHP. and you have to escape strings

Answer (score 10):

```
$myarray[1] = "hi";
$myarray[2] = "there";
$myarray[3] = "everybody";

//every quoted string should be escaped according to SQL rules
foreach($myarray as $key => $val) {
  $myarray[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
}

$in_str = "'".implode("', '", $myarray)."'"; //makes format 'hi', 'there', 'everybody' 

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE title IN ($in_str);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try use of `IN` in your `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE title IN ('hi', 'there', 'everybody');
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE title IN ('.implode(',', $myarray).');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can us the `IN` operator. You want it to look like:

```
title IN ('hi', 'there', 'everybody')
```

So you'd do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE title IN '" . implode("','", $myarray) . "';"
```

Note that you need to filter your array for SQL injection issues first.