# How to query a SQLite database using values from a Python list?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

This is Python specific therefore [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295714/array-in-sql-query) is not completely helpful.

I have a list of ids

```
[120931, 129301923, 1293019, 193923, 42939]
```

and instead of running a command for each of them with, e.g.

```
for row in c.execute(f'SELECT * from sdk WHERE app = 120931'):
    print(row)
```

**I would like to pass in the entire list of ids for 'app' and get every row where those ids appear**. Similar to the below, however with a variable (a python list) in the query

```
for row in c.execute(f'SELECT * from sdk WHERE app IN (120931, 129301923, 1293019, 193923, 42939)'):
    print(row) # passes entire list in parens but as a Python variable
```

I've tried string interpolation but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.join` to provide proper formatting for a sql `IN` statement:

```
apps = [120931, 129301923, 1293019, 193923, 42939]
c.execute(f'SELECT * from sdk WHERE app IN ({", ".join(map(str, apps))})')
```

However, if `apps` contains string values, you can use `?` notation in your statement. That way, you let sqlite3 handle the proper formatting for the statement:

```
c.execute(f'SELECT * from sdk WHERE app IN ({", ".join(["?"]*len(apps))})', apps)
```

Comment: The `?` notation is also **much** safer wrt [SQL injection](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom).  And it works just fine with the OPs integers too (I started writing my own answer until I realized you also covered parametrized queries).  In fact, parametrized queries will also avoid bombing out if one of the list's values was `None`, which needs `null`, rather than `'None'` in a non-parametrized query.